# How to update MiKTeX from 2.9 to 3.0?

Tags: miktex, miktex-update

I want to use `arrow.meta`, so I have to update MiKTeX from 2.9 to 3.0. I use `miktex-update_admin` to update MiKTeX, but the internet always breaks and even I finish the updating, the version is still 2.9.

Can anyone tell me how to how to update MiKteX from 2.9 to 3.0?

[image]

Comment: Never heard of a 3.0 version. Where did you see it?

Comment: @Bernard the correct version for `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{tikz} \begin{document} \pgfversion \end{document} ` is `3.0.1a`, but mine is `2.9`

Comment: That's a pgf version not a miktex version. Did you install pgf as admin or as user?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer so how to update pgf?

Comment: Depends on the answer of my question.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Actually, I installed tex automatically for whole process. Then how to find the files of pgf and determine admin or user?

Comment: Show in the log-file where the pgf-files are.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer there is a `install` file in `Logs` folder, and the content of `install` is [CTeX] Install=C:\CTEX Version=2.9.2.164 MiKTeX=2.9 Addons=2.9 Ghostscript=9.05 GSview=5.0 WinEdt=7.0

Comment: No, compile some document which uses pgf and check where it finds the sty etc.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer pls see the picture I updated, but this is the files in the correct version, could I just simply copy those files into the incorrect version?

Comment: As I said: show the log-file of a compilation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer pls see the updated picture, then how to see admin or user?

Comment: This is not a log-file. It is a screenshot from the windows explorer. Try to update with miktex-update.exe (not the admin version).

Answer (score 1):

[MiKTeX 3.0 is a planned release. A release date has not been fixed yet.](https://miktex.org/3.0/status)